# What does ==~ boolean operator do?

Tags: grails, groovy, operators

What does this `==~` boolean operator do in the code below?

```
springcacheCacheManager.cacheNames.each { name ->
    if (cacheNamePatterns.any { name ==~ it }) {
        flushNamedCache(name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [match operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_match_operator) performs a regex match:

```
def regex = "[A-Z]{2,}"

assert "wot" !=~ regex
assert "A" !=~ regex
assert "ABC" ==~ regex
```

In your code, if a `cacheName` matches any `cacheNamePatterns`, it will be flushed:

```
def cacheNames = ['html', 'res/images', 'res/js']

def cacheNamePatterns = ['res/.*']

def flushedCaches = []


cacheNames.each { name ->
    if (cacheNamePatterns.any { name ==~ it }) {
        flushedCaches << name
    }
}

assert flushedCaches == ['res/images', 'res/js']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is [match operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_match_operator) only available for groovy?

Comment: [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html) also has something similar, though groovy has different functionality for `=~` and `==~`. Other languages usually feature a `.match()` method.